# How can I take the first match from table B to table A when there's multiple matches?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

If I have a User table, like this:

```
UserId    Name
------    ----
1         Jim
2         Mark
```

and an Order table like this:

```
OrderId    UserId
-------    ------
1          1
2          1
3          1
4          2
```

How can I just take any single Order of Jim's? It doesn't matter which, I just want one.

I have this:

Joining isn't the issue, it's just limiting it to one result as there are obviously 3.

```
SELECT * FROM User u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order o on u.UserId = o.UserId
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want one result total, or the first match for each User?

Comment: The user will actually be specified for my use case.

Comment: So you can just use `TOP 1`. `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM User u LEFT OUTER JOIN Order o ON u.UserID = o.UserID`

Comment: @Shmiddty . . . you should add that as an answer.  I've actually been trying to post it, but I'm having trouble with my connection.

Comment: After seeing @Shmiddty's answer, I think I'm really guilty of over-thinking this. Great answer, though.

Comment: I think we're all guilty of over-thinking things at one point or another. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select the first matched row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM User u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order o ON u.UserID = o.UserID
```

If you know which user you're looking for ahead of time, you can add that to the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE u.UserID = @userID
```

And, if you ever need to make sure you're getting the First, or Most Recent order, you can use :

```
ORDER BY o.OrderID ASC/DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.userid, name, min (orderID) 
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN Order o on u.UserId = o.UserId     
group by u.userid, name
```

To filter just for Jim

```
Select min (orderID) 
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN Order o on u.UserId = o.UserId     
where name='Jim'
```

Answer (score 0):

the following query will give you one order per user (the lowest order number of each user)

```
select name, order_id 
from users u,
     orders o
where u.user_id = o.user_id 
and o.order_id = (select min(order_id) from orders c where c.user_id=o.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.userid, 
       u.name,
       o.orderid
from users u
join (select orderid, 
             userid,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by orderid) as rn
      from orders) o
  on o.userid = u.userid and o.rn = 1;
```

You can control which orders is being taken by tweaking the `order by` part of the window definition.